# What are exceptions and why "throw" them?

Tags: c#, exception

I've read many sites and other responses on StackOverflow, but I still haven't grasped the the importance of exception handling and why we "throw" them.

For this post, my understanding of an exception can best be described as:

> "An exception is a problem that arises during the execution of a program. A C# exception is a response to an exceptional circumstance that arises while a program is running..." https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_exception_handling.htm

When handling exceptions, I often see the following code snipets:

```
try 
{
    // Do something that causes an Exception
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // Could have error logging here
    throw;
}
```

If you do not perform any error logging, why have the "try/catch" and "throw" statement? The code will still throw an exception regardless of whether I try/catch. I must be missing something. What does "throwing" do?

I've included a basic *divide by zero* scenario in the following: 
https://repl.it/BjgV/24. When you remove the "try/catch/throw" you see the same results.

Comment: If you don't do anything (e.g. logging), there is no point in writing a`try`/`catch`. On the other hand, `try`/`finally` (a.k.a. `using`) has its use in disposing non-memory resources.

Comment: My personal preference is to prefer a `using` statement to ensure cleanup of disposables rather than `try/finally`, but there's a few cases where a `using` can be awkward in comparison.  Not many though.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis One could argue that adding the `try/catch/throw` is an indication that the developer was aware of the relevant exception (and by this I don't mean by catching the general `Exception`), but decided not to handle it and let it bubble up. This as opposed to not catching anything and not knowing what your code (or maybe library code) is doing.

Comment: To elaborate on other people's responses:  An exception can be thought of as an alternate mechanism for returning errors from functions.  Once thrown an exception will "return" from all functions until it is caught, all the way up the stack.  As such it is a way to make an error be somebody else's problem.

For example:  A simple console app that does a bunch of calculations based upon user input.  Rather than have each routine check for an error result, you thrown an exception and then at the top level you print out a message and tell the user that they entered bad values.

Comment: @RayFischer So you would want the last catch in the stack to do something other than throw the exception again? Like in your console example, you would have the catch statement print a statement to the user specifying an error occurred instead of throwing the error? This would allow the user to continue using the program without crashing.

Comment: Exactly.  An uncaught exception generally terminates your program so you handle it where you can do something useful rather than have each function in the call chain do a special error return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to keep in mind is not only that caught exceptions can be used for logging errors, they can be used for *handling* errors that might arise.

Let's say you have some kind of **Widget** object, that has properties you initialize via arguments to a constructor:

```
public class Widget
{
    public string Name;

    Widget(string widgetName)
    {
        if (widgetName != "")
            Name = widgetName;
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Name must be provided for widget.");
    }
}
```

In this case, we have a situation where we want to require our **Widget** have a name when it's instantiated - we check the argument to see if it's blank, and we throw an **ArgumentException** to indicate that something is wrong with one of the arguments to the constructor, as well as include a helpful message about what specifically went wrong.

This means we can then have context-specific validation logic in a wrapper, rather than having to have everything crammed into our base **Widget** class:

```
public Widget ForCaseA (string widgetName) 
{
    Widget w;

    try {
        w = new Widget(widgetname);
    }

    catch (ArgumentException as argEx) // We're specifically catching the subtype of ArgumentExceptions; generic Exceptions or other types of exception wouldn't be caught here and would bubble up out of this try/catch block.
    {
// At this point, we could look at the specific data in the exception object to determine what needs to happen to resolve the exception. Since there's only one argument and it's throwing an ArgumentException, we know it's going to be a problem with a bad widgetName. In this case, we can say 'well, in this specific case, we want to give it a default widget name'.
        w = new Widget("DefaultName");
    }

    return w;
}
```

One of the ways catching exceptions by type becomes *exceptionally* useful is when you use inheritance to create your own types based off the generic **Exception** class; e.g. giving your **Widgets** a **WidgetException**. This lets you catch issues specific to your class/entity (like the widget's name), but doesn't have to handle issues that fall outside the scope of the **Widget** itself.

Comment: In your first case, when you "throw new ArgumentException("...");" what exactly does this do? I realize it throws an error, but how does this affect the flow of the application? Does the code crash and display the error?

Comment: IIRC, throws in C# act as terminals, so a) the constructor would terminate without executing any other code, and b) flow skips over everything else until it hits either an appropriate catch block or is flagged as an unhandled exception in your IDE or program output.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine what an appropriate catch block is versus an unhandled exception. I would see a catch block that processes the error and continues on with the program (while perhaps logging the error) as appropriate, while an exception that continually gets sent up the stack trace and ends in another throw as unhandled.

Comment: If an exception is not handled by way of a catch{}, then it's unhandled and will effectively abort execution/crash your program. There's a lot of cases where this is bad - if you're writing a text editor that saves output to a file and another process locks that file for some reason, you don't want your app to crash when you're trying to save. Better to catch the I/O exception and handle it (aborting the save, warning the user so they can close the other application, etc.) than lose that work by having the application halt.

Answer (score 1):

"Throwing" is sometimes (in non-oop languages) the same as "raising" an error.

If we catch an exception, we might want to bubble that up to some method higher in the callstack, and perhaps generalize it more in the process.  Thus, we might use something like:

```
try { doSomething(); } 
catch (VerySpecificException ex) {
    throw new SomeGenericException(ex);
}
```

This allows us to expect only generic exceptions in the higher-level programming, while maintaining a full stack trace and inner exceptions so we can see where it came from.

Throw, on it's own (such as in your example), simply pushes the error up to the next caller, with no changes.  In your exact example, you might just leave out the try/catch altogether, as the result will be the same (the exception gets pushed to the next block: excepting maybe if you have some AOP or weaving in there to handle it, but that's a bit beyond this answer I think).

If there's no try/catch block, the exception is pushed back up to the next method in the callstack.  If there's no try/catch blocks anywhere, the exception is said to be "unhandled", and your application crashes.  There's no excuse for an unhandled exception to make it to the top.

Comment: When you push an error up to the next caller, does it retain the original stack trace? And is it better to error handle on higher levels as opposed to lower level functions?

Comment: @EnterTheCode The stack trace is preserved provided you use the `throw;` statement without explicitly giving it an exception.  If you did `throw ex;` that would blow away the stack trace.

Comment: Why doe specifying `throw ex;` result in losing the stack trace?

Comment: It just does, it's a given-rule type of thing.  Regarding whether it's better to handle upwards or downwards on the stack, it depends on the exception really.  Often the rule of thumb can be "handle an exception when you want to actually do something with it."  This implies that you can recover from it, but that in itself implies that it shouldn't be an exception (if you can recover from it, you know what it is, therefore not "exceptional").  "Can't save the file to disk, try another location?" is a decent example of an "actionable" exception catch.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically regarding this part:

> If you do not perform any error logging, why have the "try/catch" and "throw" statement?

Aside from logging the exception, in some situations you may want to:

- Wrap the exception in a meaningful user-defined exception which you throw to raise some error.
- Release certain resources just in case the exception happens and bubble it up for potential handling somewhere else.

These are just two examples.